# PgPool: distro vs upstream?

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.6 and would like to trial pgpool. The yum repository shows the following options:

- `pgpool-II-96`
- `postgresql-pgpool-II`

Which version should i use ? [The documentation on PgPool](http://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/en/html/index.html) references the first option, but I've found posts on here that say I should use the PostgreSQL specific repository.

Also are there any useful tutorials on getting this up and running for a first time user, i find the main documentation at pgpool.net confusing?

When I start pgpool i get the following output.

```
2018-01-31 17:51:13: pid 41278: DEBUG:  I am 41278
2018-01-31 17:51:13: pid 41278: DEBUG:  initializing backend status
2018-01-31 17:51:13: pid 41278: DEBUG:  authenticate kind = 0
2018-01-31 17:51:13: pid 41278: FATAL:  unable to read data from DB node 0
2018-01-31 17:51:13: pid 41278: DETAIL:  EOF encountered with backend
```

Comment: Documentation here: http://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/en/html/index.html I installed postgres using Yum.

Comment: I think it is quite common to use the postgresql.org (https://www.postgresql.org/download/) repos over the distro repositories. This will provide you with more recent versions. I guess the same is valid for tools like pgBackRest or (in your case) pgPool alike

Answer (score 1):

It just depends on what one you want,

- `pgpool-II-96` is provided by pgpool.net
- [`postgresql-pgpool-II`](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=postgresql-pgpool-II) is provided by your distro.

There is no right answer. Likely, I would go with distro-provided version. It's usually better integrated and I value that more than being more up to date.

As for,

> FATAL:  unable to read data from DB node 0

That's another question, but it sounds like a connectivity issue.

Comment: in regards to rhel ... the rhel distro postgres is fairly old (10.x) and I do not think that many would recommend using 10.x nowadays for a new cluster. So there is some reason behing using the postgresql.org repos over the distro.